# ToC formatting with amsbooks

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook

I'm formatting my dissertation and the template uses amsbooks. I want to remove "table of contents" from table of contents and also change the font of "list of tables" and "list of figures" to "LIST OF TABLES" "LIST OF FIGURES" in the table of contents (basically have it appear as a chapter rather than section).

I also need to indent the title "TABLE OF CONTENTS" so that it is aligned with the rest of the list. Here is what I currently have and what is specifies in the guidelines pdf:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tocchapter}[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces\MakeUppercase{#1} #2.\quad}}#3}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{DEDICATION}

A dedication

\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}

Some acknowledgments

\chapter*{ABSTRACT}

An abstract

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter*{INTRODUCTION}

An introduction

\chapter{First}
\section{A section}
\section{Another section}

\chapter{Second}

\end{document}
```

[image]